# jaxb2 annotate plugin how to annotate a javatype in global binding

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb2, annotate

using jaxb2-annotate-plugin for annotations in xsd to java. I have a xjb binding file for global bindings and want to know if we could use global bindings on javatype to add annotation. Basically what i want to do is add an annotation on a java type in all generated classes instead of adding it to each field.

plugin reference : https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin

What i am referring to is below ( this is on field level, i want it globally on javatype level ):

```
 <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='issueJIIB39CType']/xs:attribute[@name='test']">
            <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute(required=false, name="test")</annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
```

Below is where i want it so i don't have to add for each element in xsd:

```
 <jxb:globalBindings>
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
            parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"/>
</jxb:globalBindings>
```

**POM xml**

```
<artifactId>schema</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <xsd.build.dir>${basedir}/src/main/resources</xsd.build.dir>
        <generated.source.location>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/src</generated.source.location>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>B</groupId>
            <artifactId>View</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateDirectory>${generated.source.location}</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${xsd.build.dir}</schemaDirectory>
                    <addIfExistsToEpisodeSchemaBindings>true</addIfExistsToEpisodeSchemaBindings>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                             <version>1.0.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```